# Adding URL pagination for multiple custom post types in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I would like to add paginated URLs for multiple post types in WordPress.

For example when browsing post archives the following URL works automatically:

`/news/page/2`

*(Side note - I've no idea how this works, because my "Posts page" setting in Settings>Reading is empty  but clearly WordPress has magically determined that this is my posts page and therefore paginated URLs should work)*

Anyway...

I have custom post types setup for products and case studies, each with page templates that successfully list the first page of these, at the following URLs:

`/products`

`/case-studies`

I want the following to work:

`/products/page/2`

`/case-studies/page/2`

But of course right now these just give me 404 errors - presumably because WordPress is looking for actual pages that match these URLs, rather than treating the `/page/2` part as pagination.

For clarity, my page templates and code for listing news, products and case studies are essentially identical, but only news works for anything beyond the first page of results.

**NOTE:**
My question is not how to add custom post types, how to read URL parameters, or how to use WP_Query - I know all of these things.

It is very specifically how to ensure URLs such as `/products/page/2` actually load the content from the `/products` page whilst allowing me to retrieve and use the page number with PHP and pass this to the `paged` parameter of the WP_Query being used on this page template.

Given built-in support for custom post types, I assume there must absolutely be built-in support for paginating those post types, but I cannot find it.

Otherwise, I guess the only option would be some sort of URL rewriting, but that sounds like a very bodged solution.

Thanks for any help

Comment: Of course this is built-in already, f.e. the `register_post_type ` parameters include the `rewrite` option, part of which is `pages` to determine whether the permalink structure for pagination should be created, https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_post_type/#rewrite